# Error al migrar base de datos de SQL Server 2014 a Oracle 19c

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, sql-server-2014, oracle-19c

Necesito migrar una base de datos de SQL Server 2014 a Oracle 19c, estoy utilizando la herramienta de SQL Server con el JTDS 1.3.1, mientras se esta realizando la migración en el paso de "Mover los datos" me devuelve un mensaje que dice:

```
Se ha restablecido la conexión al usuario sys, todos los cambios se han perdido
```

La migración continúa y después de alrededor de 5 min. obtenfo el mensaje de que la migración ha finalizado correctamente pero al revisar el esquema migrado no tengo ninguna tabla, ni valores, ¿saben a que se debe esto? y ¿Cómo se resolvería?

Comment: ¿Qué versión de SQL Developer estás usando?

Comment: Normalmente no uso la conexión SYS para una migración, ¿puedes probar con el propietario de tu SCHEMA?

Comment: Es la versión 20.2, ¿sería con el esquema que voy a migrar? Es decir si en SQL Server la BD se llama Prueba en Oracle debería de obtener el esquema Prueba, sugieres que cree este esquema antes de realizar la migración?

Comment: Lo siento, no dije eso muy bien. No cree el repositorio de migración en SYS. Crea un usuario llamado 'repositorio' o similar. La rutina de migración creará su nuevo usuario para que coincida con el nombre de la base de datos SQL.

Comment: Aaa si, tengo un usuario aparte el cual se llama REPOSITORIO asocie un repositorio de migración a este, y es que me sucede este error, el usuario SYS lo coloco en el paso 8 del asistente de migración, en el que te solicita colocarla conexión donde se ejecutara el script

Comment: Reviso el archivo .log y veo que las tablas no están con la sintaxis de Oracle, tienen sintaxis de SQL Server